# How to sort by the first letter of a word in Livedata Recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I have dataclass retrofit from json and a LiveData.I'm sending the adapter list with observe.How to sort by the first letter of a word in observe?**

```
private fun getAllTeams(){
    viewModel.getMyGroupMembers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it.sortedBy {
                it.name
            }
           it.forEach {
               it.name.toCharArray().sorted().joinToString("")

           }
        Log.d("sort",it.toString())

        scoreAdapter.submitList(it)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


    })
}
```

**I tried something but it dosent work**

```
class ScoreViewModel(private val scoreApi: ScoreApi) : ViewModel() {

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private val myGroupMembers = MutableLiveData<List<DataClass>>()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun getMyGroupMembers(): LiveData<List<DataClass>> = myGroupMembers


fun getAllGroups(){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       val response =  scoreApi.getAllGroups()
        updateUi(response)
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun updateUi(update: List<DataClass>) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        myGroupMembers.value = update
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortedBy` method is used when you want to make a copy of your list. Its usually used when your main List is not Mutable:

```
val sortedList = it.sortedBy { it.name }
```

If you want to sort in-place without copying it you can use `sortBy` extension. This will only work if your list is Mutable.

```
it.sortBy { it.name }
```